# How to restrict some entries to not save which is in association in rails.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, parameters

I have two tables which are associated together. Which mean

**A ---(has_many)---> B**

so it gives params like this

```
A =>{xx => "sample",
     yy => "sample",
     ...,
     ...,
     B => {check => "yes",
           pp => "b-sample",
           ....
           ....
          }
     }
```

so in this i need to check if B's check is == "yes" mean it should not save the record to table B.

How do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Found in this way:

By adding `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in Model A like this

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :a_paramname, :reject_if => lambda { |con| con[:check] == 'yes' }
```

which will reject action record which are all satisfying lambda condition and saves other records.

Answer (score 0):

> Say A = User model
>
> and B = Email model

`User has_many :emails`

Create a `scope` for it in **Model Email**, like:

```
scope :unchecked, -> { where("check <> 'yes'") }
```

Then iterate over following and update

```
User.first.emails.unchecked
```

Comment: Its not working and can we work this with ` accepts_nested_attributes_for ` which mean `:reject_if  => "condition"`. Here i dont know whether it accepts condition or not.

Comment: Yeah... i just used your idea the code which i given in my question is a sample. and it is not working. And scope is something for showing rite..? which mean we can filter if it has checked value. I need something to not even allows to save in.

Comment: Without any code it's confusing. What I suggested is one idea of getting unchecked associated records and manually updating them